# "Add one" to every color in an image

Tags: code-golf, image-processing, hexadecimal

You would simply take this image and make every color added one to every hexadecimal digit. For example, `#49de5f` would become `#5aef60` (with the `9` looping to an `a`, and the `f` looping to a `0`.)

[image: Color #49de5f][image: Color #5aef60]

This would also mean that all white (`#ffffff`) would become black (`#000000`) because all `f` loops back to `0`, but all black will become a lighter shade of black (`#111111`).

[image: Color #000000][image: Color #111111]

Scoring is based on the least number of bytes used, as this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question.

Use the below image as the input image for your code, and put the output image of your code into your answer.

[image: Input image]

If you want to, you can also use this other rainbow image:

[image: Another optional input image]

Comment: What assumptions can we make on input/output format, if we would like to use a programming language designed for hardware/FPGA design?

Comment: @hexafraction I think by default you can take as a file or as hex code iirc.

Comment: @hexafraction http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9093/8478

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks. I'm still a bit unclear in regard to output *timing* due to the nature of Verilog as an HDL; should I pop into the site chat to seek further clarification?

Comment: @hexafraction Either that or ask on meta.

Comment: @Peanut, it would be good to have a test case which includes `ef` bytes (which should become `f0` as opposed to `00` which happens when you just add 17 and take mod 256).

Comment: You should post an image for sample output, rather than just providing sample input. Other than that, this is a very nice first post! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Pyke, <s>17</s> 13 bytes

```
.Fh16j%ijcjs 8{
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.Fh16%25i16%2B%2B8%7B&input=%5B%5B%5B0%2C31%2C15%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C0%5D%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C255%5D%2C%5B0xef%2C0xee%2C0xf0%5D%5D%0A)

```
.F            - for i in deep_for(input):
  h16%        -    (i+1)%16
          +   -   ^+V
      i16+    -    (i+16)
           8{ -  unset_bit(8, ^)
```

Takes input as a 3d integer array of pixels and outputs in the same format

[image: RAINBOWZ (No unicorn :()]

Comment: Can you provide the output image?

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica, 78 bytes

```
Image@Apply[16#+#2&,Mod[IntegerDigits[#~ImageData~"Byte",16,2]+1,16]/255,{3}]&
```

Takes and returns an image object (to create an image object, just paste the image into Mathematica).

Result for the test case:

[image]

[Taking input](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9103/8478) and [returning output](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9104/8478) as a 3D array of integer channel values, this reduces to **51 bytes**:

```
Apply[16#+#2&,Mod[IntegerDigits[#,16,2]+1,16],{3}]&
```

But those meta posts don't have an overwhelming amount of support yet, so I'm going with the 78-byte version for now.

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 226 bytes

Now, it's valid !

Use the Pillow library.

```
from PIL import Image
m=Image.open(input()).convert("RGB")
for y in range(m.size[1]):
 for x in range(m.size[0]):
    t=m.getpixel((x,y))
    h=t[0]+(t[1]<<8)+(t[2]<<16)+1118481
    m.putpixel((x,y),(h&255,h>>8&255,h>>16&255))
m.show()
```

Output:[image: Output]

Thanks to @TuukkaX for saving 9 bytes !
Thanks to @mbomb007 for saving 18 bytes !

Comment: Is it necessary to use `0xFF` instead of `255`?

Comment: @TuukkaX Woops i haven't noticed that thanks you

Comment: There is one more `0xFF` in there :D

Comment: I think you can save more bytes by saying `from PIL import*`. I also think that `Image.open` can be changed to just `open` after that.

Comment: @TuukkaX Yes, it can be changed to `from PIL import*`, but i can't change the `Image.open`

Comment: Oh okay. I'm pretty sure that `(h>>8)&255` can be changed to `h>>8&255` and `(h>>16)&255` to `h>>16&255`.

Comment: Also, you can save 2 bytes by removing the outer parentheses when you're defining the variable `h`.

Comment: @TuukkaX Thanks you ! Oh and `from PIL import*` don't work :c

Comment: No problem! It doesn't work since `open` is an built in function in Python so it meets a collision when importing everything from PIL :(

Comment: You can combine 2 lines with `m.putpixel((x,y),(h&255,h>>8&255,h>>16&255))`, and `0x111111` can become `1118481`.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks you

Comment: And some [spaces can become tabs](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#from%20PIL%20import%20Image%0Am%3DImage.open%28input%28%29%29.convert%28%22RGB%22%29%0Afor%20y%20in%20range%28m.size%5B1%5D%29%3A%0A%20for%20x%20in%20range%28m.size%5B0%5D%29%3A%0A%09t%3Dm.getpixel%28%28x%2Cy%29%29%0A%09h%3Dt%5B0%5D%2B%28t%5B1%5D%3C%3C8%29%2B%28t%5B2%5D%3C%3C16%29%2B1118481%0A%09m.putpixel%28%28x%2Cy%29%2C%28h%26255%2Ch%3E%3E8%26255%2Ch%3E%3E16%26255%29%29%0Am.show%28%29). See [this tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58/34718).

Comment: golfing your solution a bit further, I have 216 bytes : 
```from PIL import Image```
```R,m=range,Image.open(input()).convert("RGB")```
```L=m.load()```
```W,H=m.size```
```def X(*p):t=L[p];h=t[0]+(t[1]<<8)+(t[2]<<16)+1118481;L[p]=h&255,h>>8&255,h>>16&255```
```[X(x,y)for x in R(W)for y in R(H)]```
```m.show()```

Answer (score 4):

## Verilog, 220 bytes:

> - Programs may take input as an array of RGB pixel values with dimensions
> - Programs may output via an array of RGB pixel values with dimensions

It's currently not clear as to how the dimensions are to be provided and if the array is to be streamed or provided all at once. I'm going to stream it 8 bits at a time using a clock signal (with a valid-data flag that goes low after the entire image has been processed) and input/output the dimensions as 32-bit integers:

```
module a(input[31:0]w,input[31:0]h,input[7:0]d,input c,output[31:0]W,output[31:0]H,output reg[7:0]D,output reg v=0);assign W=w;assign H=h;reg[65:0]p=1;always@(posedge c) begin v<=(p<3*w*h); p<=p+v; D<=d+17; end endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>21</s> 15 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9411/43319)

> Programs may output as a matrix of RGB pixel values

I assume output may be in the same format.

#### New solution takes matrix of values [[*r*,*g*,*b*,*r*,*g*,*b*],[*r*,*g*,*b*,…

```
16⊥16|1+16 16⊤⎕
```

**Explanation**

`⎕` get numeric input
`16 16⊤` convert to 2-digit base 16
`1+` add 1, i.e. 0 → 1, 1 → 2, 15 → 16
`16|` modulus 16, i.e. 16 → 0
`16⊥` convert from base 16

**Example**

```
      ⊢m←2 6⍴90 239 96 255 255 255 0 0 0 239 239 239
90 239 96 255 255 255
 0   0  0 239 239 239
      16⊥16|1+⎕⊤⍨2/16
⎕:
      m
107 240 113   0   0   0
 17  17  17 240 240 240
```

---

#### Old 21 byte solution takes matrix of [["RRGGBB","RRGGBB"],["RRGGBB",…

```
{n[16|1+⍵⍳⍨n←⎕D,⎕A]}¨
```

Needs `⎕IO←0`, which is default on many systems.

**Explanation**

`{`…`}¨` for each RGB 6-char string, represent it as `⍵` and do:
`n←⎕D,⎕A` assign "0…9A…Z" to *n*
`⍵⍳⍨` find indices of the individual characters in *n*
`1+` add one to the index, i.e. 0 → 1, 1 → 2, 15 → 16
`16|` modulus 16, i.e. 16 → 0
`n[`…`]` use that to index into *n*

**Example**

```
      f←{n[16|1+⍵⍳⍨n←⎕D,⎕A]}¨ 
      ⊢p←2 2⍴'5AEF60' 'FFFFFF' '000000' 'EFEFEF'
┌──────┬──────┐
│5AEF60│FFFFFF│
├──────┼──────┤
│000000│EFEFEF│
└──────┴──────┘
      f p           
┌──────┬──────┐
│6BF071│000000│
├──────┼──────┤
│111111│F0F0F0│
└──────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

## C - <s>114</s> <s>113</s> <s>70</s> <s>66</s> <s>61</s> <s>72</s> 67 bytes

Here's the code (with support for **Martin Ender**'s test case (without it's 60b)):

```c
main(c,b){for(;~(b=getchar());putchar(c++<54?b:b+16&240|b+1&15));}
```

And here is less obfuscated version:

```c
main( c, b ) //Defaults to int
{
    //Get characters until EOF occurs
    //Copy first 54 bytes of header, later add 1 to each hexadecimal digit
    for ( ; ~( b = getchar( ) ); putchar( c++ < 54 ? b: b + 16 & 240 | b + 1 & 15 ) ); 
}
```

Compile and run with `gcc -o color colorgolf.c && cat a.bmp | ./color > b.bmp`

This code supports works with **bitmaps**. To convert `png` files to `bmp`, I used following command: `convert -flatten -alpha off png.png a.bmp`

Code assumes, that `bmp` header is 54 bytes long - in this case it works, but I'm not sure if I'm not discreetly breaking something.

Also, this is the rainbow:
[image: It looks sad now... :(]

Answer (score 1):

## Java 142 bytes

```
public BufferedImage translateColor(BufferedImage image){
  for(int i=-1;++i<image.getWidth();)
    for(int j=-1;++<image.getHeight();)
      image.setRGB(i,j,image.getRGB(i,j)+1118481);
  return image;
}
```

Golfed:

```
BufferedImage t(BufferedImage i){for(int x=-1;++x<i.getWidth();)for(int y=-1;++y<i.getHeight();)i.setRGB(x,y,i.getRGB(x,y)+1118481);return i;}
```

Comment: First of all welcome to PPCG! Your code-golfed code uses the `i` both as parameter and in the for-loop, so I would change the parameter to something else like `a`. Also, you can golf it some more by removing the `int ` in front of the `j` and add it to the `int i`. So like this: `BufferedImage t(BufferedImage a){for(int i=-1,j;++i<a.getWidth();)for(j=-1;++j<a.getHeight();)a.setRGB(i,j,a.getRGB(i,j)+1118481);return a;}`. Also, have a look at this post: [Tips for golfing in Java](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java). :)

Comment: You're not setting the colors correctly.  By adding 0x111111 to the RGB values, you have the possibility of overflow from one hexadecimal place to the next.  For example, #49de5f is supposed to become #5aef60, not #5aef70.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 302 bytes

Far from perfect, but here goes:

```
a<-as.raster(imager::load.image(file.choose()));l=letters;n=as.numeric;d=a;f=function(x){if(suppressWarnings(is.na(n(x)))){if(x=="F")"0" else{l[match(x,toupper(l))+1]}}else{if(x==9)"A" else as.character(n(x)+1)}};for(o in 1:90){for(g in 1:200){for(h in 2:7){substr(d[o,g],h,h)<-f(substr(a[o,g],h,h))}}}
```

Explanation:

```
a<-as.raster(imager::load.image(file.choose()));  //chooses file
l=letters;n=as.numeric;d=a;                      //shortens some names and creates
                                                   duplicate variable to modify

f=function(x){                                //creates a function that takes in a
   if(suppressWarnings(is.na(n(x)))){            character type and checks whether it is
      if(x=="F")"0"                              a number or letter.
      else{l[match(x,toupper(l))+1]}}            Returns the converted letter or number.                               
   else{                                   
      if(x==9)"A"                         
      else as.character(n(x)+1)}         
};                                      

for(o in 1:90){                       //loops through every single hex digit and applies
   for(g in 1:200){                     the converting function, modifying the duplicate
      for(h in 2:7){                    variable. Now you have 2 images =D

         substr(d[o,g],h,h)<-f(substr(a[o,g],h,h))

      }
   }
}
```

[image: a beautiful rainbow]